# extend inner java class from groovy in grails 2.2.3

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have mixin java and groovy code as below inside a `grails 2.2.3` app,

```
├── src
│   ├── groovy
│   │   └── eccount
│   │       ├── Query.groovy      // extends Queries.DefaultQuery
│   │       ├── Listener.groovy 
│   │       ├── Elasticsearch.groovy 
│   │       ├── Queries.groovy   // extends ElaticsearchQueries
│   └── java
│       └── eccount
│           ├── ElasticsearchQueries.java // public class
│           ├── EsServer.java
```

I have been using `src/java` mostly from `grails-app/services` definitely written in **`groovy`** which is fine. But when tried to access existing `src/java` from `src/groovy` looks strange.

The `ElasticsearchQueries.java` factory class is as below,

```
package eccount;
public class ElasticsearchQueries {
         public static class DefaultQuery implements IQuery {
                 //
         }
}
```

Groovy implementation class is as below,

```
package eccount;
public class Queries extends ElasticsearchQueries {
                 //
}

package eccount;
public class Query extends Queries.DefaultQuery {
                 //
}
```

As per my understanding it should have worked. But I assume its some other issues.

Here's the stacktrace of `grails clean && grails compile`,

```
 src/groovy/eccount/Query.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class Queries.DefaultQuery 
 @ line 3, column 1.
   public class Query extends Queries.DefaultQuery {
   ^

1 error
```

Github code - [gccount-groovy-groovy-java](https://github.com/iPrayag/gccount/blob/java-groovy/gccount-groovy-groovy-java/src/java/eccount/ElasticsearchQueries.java)

Comment: *package* does not exist. Show the code..

Comment: Its problem in your code (probably in your package). Java and groovy compilation work in same manner.

Comment: So `DefaultQuery` is an inner class of `eccount.ElasticsearchQueries`?

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes, it's static defined inner class.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  I just tested it myself in 2.2.3 (a brand new `create-app` with your two files added) and it works fine for me.

Comment: (well, it failed initially because I'd named the file `ElasticsearchQueries.java` rather than `ElaticsearchQueries.java`...)

Comment: @IanRoberts `grails 2.2.3`

Comment: Are you sure you have the right `package` declarations at the top of both the `.java` and `.groovy` files?  Judging by the directory structure you describe they should both be `package eccount;`

Comment: @IanRoberts apologies for consuming your time, I mismatched things here. It's actually groovy to groovy to java inner class. I've updated the question. Also github-code is here in a branch- [gccount-groovy-groovy-java](https://github.com/iPrayag/gccount/blob/java-groovy/gccount-groovy-groovy-java/src/java/eccount/ElasticsearchQueries.java).

Comment: Does it work if you move the `java` class into the groovy folder?

Comment: @tim_yates No, `mv src/java/eccount/ElasticsearchQueries.java src/groovy/eccount/` or `mv src/java/eccount/ElasticsearchQueries.java src/groovy/eccount/ElasticsearchQueries.groovy` doesn't work.